# mysql self relationship with 2 field

Tags: php, mysql, relationship

I have `user` table like this:

```
  id          email
-------------------------
  1       test@gmail.com
```

And `menu` table like this:

```
  id   parent_id   user_id   name
-----------------------------------
  1       NULL        1      tets
```

I would like to self relationship `parent_id` AND `user_id`.
If hacker wanna to add this record mysql ignored this action, Because `user_id` **2** not owner parent menu **1**!!! :

```
  id   parent_id   user_id   name
-----------------------------------
  2       1           2      tets
```

Comment: If some one add a record to menu with  an user id which is not present in the user table it shouldn't be added. Have I got your requirement correct....?

Comment: @AndrewsBAnthony Yes. `user_id` field in relationship with `user` table AND `parent_id` self relationship with `id`. I have one problem with self relationship `user_id` to `user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.create table **User** using below query

```
create table User(id int primary key,email varchar(30));
```

2.create table **Menu** using the below query

```
create table Menu(id,int,u_id int,p_id int,name varchar(10),primary key(u_id,p_id),
    constraint user_fk foreign key(id) references User(id) 
      on delete cascade);
```

when you enter a value which is not present in the table User then below error will be thrown

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: Could you please give some sample records...? and give me the error details

Comment: Use question sample records.

Comment: i've changee the second query now it should work...@yonessafari

Comment: I need 3 relationship. `menu.user_id` to `user.id` , `menu.parent_id` to `menu.id` , `menu.user_id`  to `menu.user_id`

Comment: what exactly are you going to do with those tables,,